# XML Parse with Date(parameter)

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to parse xml but I have a problem:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ipadress/web_service/list.php?DATE=%@",dateSinc];
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else{

}
```

when the dateSinc is **2013-02-04** example it works but when is **2013-02-04 09:47:00** it doesn't work(the connection not respond)... but in browser works..

Comment: use dateFormatter and change `dateSinc` format to `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: but I need the hours, minutes and seconds...dateSinc is the last updated date...if have two updates in a day..I need in this format..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue relates to not properly encoding the URL, so the web server isn't seeing the date you want:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ipadress/web_service/list.php?DATE=%@",dateSinc];
NSString *encodedURL = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedURL]];
// etc.
```